# Data conversion error with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i am in the process of making mu code nicer and i saw that numpy has some very nifty functions already built-in. However the following code throws an error that i cannot 
explain:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('table.oout',unpack=True,names=True,dtype=None)

real_ov_data=np.float32(data['real_overlap'])
ana_ov_data= np.float32(data['Analyt_overlap'])
length_data =np.float32(data['Residues'])

plot(length_data,real_ov_data,label="overlapped Peaks, exponential function",marker="x", markeredgecolor="blue", markersize=3.0, linestyle=" ",color="blue")
plot(length_data,ana_ov_data,label="expected overlapped Peaks",marker="o", markeredgecolor="green", markersize=3.0, linestyle=" ",color="green")
```

throws the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "length_vs_overlap.py", line 52, in <module>
    real_ov_data=np.float32(data['real_overlap'])
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): real_overlap
>Exit code: 1
```

when i am trying to read the following file:

```
  'Residues'  'Analyt_overlap'  'anz_analyt_overlap'  'real_overlap' 
  21          1.2502        29            0.0000  
  13          1.0306        25            0.0000  
  56          5.8513        84            2.8741  
  190         68.0940       329           28.4706 
  54          5.4271        83            2.4999
```

What am i doing wrong? My piece of code should be simple enough?

Comment: It might help to see what gets printed out when you iterate through `data`, perhaps this `numpy.genfromtxt('table.oout',unpack=True,names=True,dtype=None)` isn't doing exactly what you think.

Comment: This works for me, the data loads just fine. An aside, you shouldn't have two namespaces for `numpy`. You have both `numpy.` and `np.`. I'd remove one of those import statements and unify it.

Comment: The fact that the data loads on the minimal example posted suggests that you are doing something fishy in the 50 lines of code before the error. Can you post a _complete_ example where this fails, including all needed import statements?

Comment: ok, but the code is too long to be pasted here. i will just upload both code and data to pastebin.

Comment: code: http://pastebin.com/d3AsrSuc, table: http://pastebin.com/iP21ZYJS

Comment: @tarrasch I _still_ don't have a problem when I run your code - the plot shows up just fine. Maybe the error is in the file `table.oout`. Mind posting that too?

Answer (score 1):

You've either repeated the header line, or you're specifying the `names` as a list.

That's causing each column to be read as a string type starting with the column title.